# Geopackage: convert BLOB to coordinates

Tags: sqlite, type-conversion, blob, coordinates, geopackage

I'm working with SQLite-Mananger Plugin for FireFox to edit my local geopackage database.

The geometry is stored as BLOB in various tables. 
Now I'd like to encode the not readable BLOB format into human readable coordinates.

I already tried it that way:

```
Select STAsText(geometry) as geometry from table;
```

With the following error:

```
no such function: STAsText
```

I guess because it is a local database and the STAsText-function is for SQL-Sever.

I also tried it with:

```
SELECT quote(geometry) FROM table
```

But with this I also get no coordinates.

Comment: Use SpatiaLite. It might be possible to load it into SQLite Manager as an extension DLL.

Comment: I need to use geopackage as the database format. I'll take a look to specific spatiallite functions that I can use in sqlitemanager via DDL extension. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just use GDAL OGR2OGR "ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON"  path/filename.geojson path/filename.gpkg"
Or use QGIS Desktop.   GeoPackage uses a derivation of WKB -Well Known Binary for it's Vector Features BLOB.  Conversion to GeoJSON is very straight forward. You can also use GeoPackage-JS to do the conversion. 
Click Open Geopackage and it will allow you to download as GeoJSON http://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-js/